# Numpy: How to calculate standard deviation of a signal v(t) with non-uniform samples

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Lets say I have two numpy arrays:

```
y(n) = [y1, y2, y3...]
t(n) = [t1, t2, t3...]
```

`y(n)` represents the value of a signal at time point `t(n)`.
Now, I want to calculate statistical quantities like standard deviation etc for this signal.
I can use the standard numpy function `std()` if the samples were taken at an uniform time interval. In my case, the samples are not taken in uniform time interval. That is, `t2-t1` may not be equal to `t3-t2`.

I am thinking of creating a new array, which would be created by interpolating the values of `y`.

```
g = [g1, g2, g3...] where
ts = np.min(np.diff(t)) # new sample size
g(n) = numpy.interp(n*ts, t, y) # interpolate
```

Now use `g` in place of `y` to calculate `std` etc.
I am wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Standard deviation of a signal is calculated under an assumption that y(n) are independent random variables taken from the same probability distribution. With non-uniform sampling this assumption may not be true if the distribution of sampling times is correlated with the signal. Web search points to a recent dissertation where computing statistics from non-uniformly sampled signals is discussed at length http://liu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:23251/FULLTEXT01.pdf

Comment: In my case, it is not a random variable. It is a sequence of values observed from a physical event at specific time points. This is supposed to be a constant in the ideal case. The standard deviation is used to measure how bad it is comparing to the ideal case.
Thanks for the link. I will check if I can utilize any insight from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To interpolate and resample is one approach, but it's easier to use non-uniform time intervals as weights. That is, to average something over time, multiply each value by the corresponding time interval; take the sum; and divide by the total time elapsed.

```
dt = np.diff(t)
total_time = t[-1] - t[0]
mean = np.dot(y[:-1], dt)/total_time
std = np.sqrt(np.dot((y[:-1]-mean)**2, dt)/total_time)
```

With n samples you end up with n-1 time intervals (in the array dt), so one of the samples (the last one) gets discarded, as we don't know the time period for it. This should not matter unless the number of sample is very small.